# Reset password - set minimum length for new password

Tags: password, reset

I’m trying to set a minimum length for the new password when resetting the password. I would like to add something like this just functional.

```
add_action( 'password_reset', 'reset_my_password', 10, 2 );
function reset_my_password($user, $new_pass, $errors) {
$errors = new WP_Error();
if ( strlen( $_POST['new_pass'] ) < 8 ) {
$errors->add( 'password_too_short', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Password is too short." );
}
}
```

Any help with this would appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [validate_password_reset](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/validate_password_reset/) hook instead.

Try

```
add_action( 'validate_password_reset' , 'se_password_min_length_check' 10, 2 );

function se_password_min_length_check( $errors, $user){
    if(strlen($_POST['pass1']) < 8)
        $errors->add( 'password_too_short', 'ERROR: password is too short.' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you after I added $priority and $accepted_args this worked for me.